# while read line, only reading last line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a little bash script that should read a file and play each line in mplayer. But it only plays 1 second of each file then goes on to the next song. Only the last line in the file is being played properly. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/home/dummy/list.m3u

echo "################################"
while IFS= read -r line
        do
            echo "loadfile '$line'" > /tmp/mplayer.fifo
done < $file
```

The lines in the file just contains the path to the mp3s like this: /home/dummy/song.mp3

How can I play each line and after the song ends start the next song?

Also, is there a way to read the lines in a random order?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>` for _appending_.

Answer (score 3):

> Only the last line in the file is being played properly.

Use `>>` instead of `>` for *appending*.  You are using `>` which overwrites the file every time, due to which you see only the last line in the file.

> Also, is there a way to read the lines in a random order?

You could use `shuf` or `sort`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "loadfile '$line'" >> /tmp/mplayer.fifo
done < <(shuf $file)
```

Saying `sort -R filename` would perform random sort.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply: the shuf $file seems to work, but it still only plays one song.

Comment: @user3343273 That must be because you are using `>` and not `>>`.

Comment: This is what my script looks like now:

Comment: echo "loadfile '$line'" >> /tmp/mplayer.fifo

Comment: and still only one song is playing.

Comment: @user3343273 This looks like something to do with `mplayer`.  Sorry, I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/home/dummy/list.m3u
shuf -n file > randomshuffled
echo "################################"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        echo "loadfile '$line'" >> /tmp/mplayer.fifo
done < $( cat randomshuffled)
```

See the `>>` for appending lines in file. If you want to clear the queue and start with your new songs - just add line `echo "" > /tmp/mplayer.fifo` before the `while` loop

And the `shuf file > randomshuffled` for random shuffle of rows in file

You can also use

```
mplayer -shuffle -playlist /home/dummy/list.m3u
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply I used you example, but there is an error: ./script.sh: line 9: $randomshuffled: ambiguous redirect

Comment: `randomshuffled` is a file, not a variable, so the `$` in the redirection is causing the problem.